# JavaScript OPTIONS object doesn't change

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

We have the following code:

```js
/**
     * @type {object}
     */
    Object.defineProperty(DateTimePicker.prototype,
        "OPTIONS",
        {
            enumerable: true,
            get: function () {
                return {
                    useStrict: false,
                    format: this.FORMAT,
                    maxDate: this.MAX_DATE,
                    minDate: this.MIN_DATE,
                    defaultDate: null,
                    viewDate: null,
                    icons: this.ICONS
                };
            }
        });
```

In other places of the code we're using

```js
let value = services.Date.momentFromDateString(val).format(this.FORMAT);
                        this.OPTIONS.defaultDate = value;
                        this.OPTIONS.viewDate = value;
```

However, I examine, this.OPTIONS.defaultDate right after assignment and it remains null.

What is wrong in the above code and how can I change it in order to being able to change default date and view value in code? I don't understand why the assignment does nothing although doesn't generate any error either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OPTIONS`'s getter remains static - it keeps returning a newly created object (where defaultDate and viewDate are null) whenever it's called. You can assign to the returned object, but immediately afterwards, no reference to that object remains, and further calls return *new* objects, so the change is never seen.

You might want to define the OPTIONS property in the constructor instead.